# Which command can I use overwrite the boot loader?

Tags: windows, multi-boot

Grub was installed onto my machine as part of an Ubuntu installation. I'm now reverting my machine to be Windows only, and so no longer require the Grub boot loader. How do I remove Grub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time, all you needed was to boot into Windows and run this on the commandline:

```
C:\> fdisk /mbr
```

But not anymore.  You'll need to use the Windows Recovery Console (from a Windows boot/install CD). So you need to boot into the Recovery Console and run this:

```
> fixboot
```

Or this:

```
> fixmbr [device]
```

Use the MAP command to find the correct [device] parameter.

[Win2000 Recover Console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229716)

Answer (score 2):

On Vista? [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) did it for me. Literally one click, was very impressed.
For XP, somebody else'll have to chime in.

Comment: Actually it is Windows 2000.

Comment: Then the answer below is more appropriate :)